# Golang sending email without authority

Tags: go, smtp

I am writing a golang program to send a email to my gmail account to report some problem. 
Here is my code:

```
c, err := smtp.Dial("aspmx.l.google.com:25")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("dial err ", err)
}

if err := c.Mail("report@mbytetech.com"); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Mail err ", err)
}
if err := c.Rcpt("zing.luke@gmail.com"); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Rcpt err ", err)
}
wc, err := c.Data()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Data err ", err)
}
_, err = fmt.Fprintln(wc, "In your face, Neil Armstrong")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("writer err ", err)
}
err = wc.Close()
if err != nil {
    // log.Fatal(err)
    fmt.Print(err)
    return
}
err = c.Quit()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("quit err ", err)
}
```

I don't actually have a email account as "report@mbytetech.com"(But I do have a gmail account "zing.luke@gmail.com"). I just want it to be shown as "sender" in the email. And my boss told me that he doesn't want to really create a email account to do the "send" work.

Evertime I run this program, it always give me an error said "421 4.7.0 [54.176.117.9      15] Our system has detected an unusual rate of...". And I never got a email in my inbox.

I look up the [Google smtp server](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) and [Google bulk mail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126). But I just can't find any solution.

Please someone help me out, I really appreciate that!

Comment: The first link you've given says that you need to set up SPF records to use the aspmx mail server.  It might be better to use your company or ISP's local mail server as a relay for your messages rather than sending to Google directly.

Comment: The IP in your error indicates you're sending from Amazon EC2. Since anyone, anywhere can get an EC2 instance, many automated filters are suspicious that messages they send might be spam. Amazon's approach to this is to offer [Simple E-mail Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/), though there are other e-mail sending providers as well.